# Pygame detecting any keydown instead of just 'S' key

Tags: python, pygame

When running the following lines of code, a user should press the 'W' button to start meditating, and press the 'S' button to stop meditating, however what I'm finding is that if ANY button is pressed, the user starts or stops meditating depending on whether DL[19] = 4 or 0. This is a problem as I need the keys 'A' and 'D' to navigate through rooms. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
        if DL[19] == 0: # no activity
            displaydata1 = font.render(" 'W' Key: meditate", True, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(displaydata1, (coordinates[0], coordinates[1] + 14))
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.K_w:
                    DL[19] = 4 # set activity to meditating

        elif DL[19] == 4: # meditating
            displaydata1 = font.render(" 'S' Key: stop meditating", True, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(displaydata1, (coordinates[0], coordinates[1] + 14))
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.K_s:
                    DL[19] = 0 # set to no activity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if DL[19] == 0: # no activity
            displaydata1 = font.render(" 'W' Key: meditate", True, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(displaydata1, (coordinates[0], coordinates[1] + 14))
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_w:
                    DL[19] = 4 # set activity to meditating

        elif DL[19] == 4: # meditating
            displaydata1 = font.render(" 'S' Key: stop meditating", True, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(displaydata1, (coordinates[0], coordinates[1] + 14))
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_s:
                    DL[19] = 0 # set to no activity
```

You say `event.type == pygame.K_w` to see if "w" was clicked